# Apache can't display some images in same folder

Tags: php, apache, jpeg, image-uploading

I have more than 4500 images uploaded in the same folder. I'm uploading images with a php script. It was working fine but today i can't see images on web browser.

I can see a.jpg but i can't see b.jpg. All files have same size (3MB), same type (jpeg) and same access (644).

I tried to download the image to my disk with FTP. I can see on my mac. But i can't see on web browser.

Comment: Are you get any errors while you are trying to display them? Do files have same owners?

Comment: all files have same owners. when i tracking file with chrome inspector, its no problem. file is downloading. content type is image/jpeg, status code is 200. but i see broken link image.

Comment: file is here: http://www.jadorestore.com/uploads/9880275922061on.jpg

Comment: Your file has different than jpg mime-type `9880275922061on.jpg: image/tiff`.

Comment: ty marian. my creative customer have interesting idea like a rename file name for convert tiff to jpeg.